# Getting started with google gadgets

Tags: google-apps-script

i am still trying to get my first gadget working....
so i followed the help, 
openend my site, openend the scripts, added a script, made a html-type ui, published for each  semicomma i changed a version since otherwise there seems no way to test the script prior to publishing it, in the exe window it looks ok, so now i wanted to embed it into the site....

and ,,, it doesn't appear ....
added "by URL"
well so i pasted the exes page URL into it, and i get a 
Unsupported feature: org.apache.shindig.common.xml.XmlException: The element type "meta" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "". At: (1383,5)

so i am stuck... how do i get my gadget onto the page???

URL is https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwbTcSDuGZLy1eNlAHjrewkmOm5ZHkDQsze3CPP4-M/dev

ciao
Bruno

Comment: The url you show here is a 'dev' url only accessible by yourself...(and that you can use to test your app without changing the 'version') the url to use for publishing ends with 'exec'. Also in the 'insert gadget' you should normally see your gadget  in a list of available scripts... so choose it there instead

Answer (score 0):

The url of a gadget on a web page looks like this :

```
https://sites.google.com/macros/exec?service=AKfycbxLvE49lcgdQlvw3ouxLnjEvYwgdiOPH5ecNYClzw
```

The script has to be saved with a version and published (deployed) before it can be inserted.

Could you tell us if you have the script shown in the list of available scripts in 'manage this site' (see below)

[image]

and then when you try to insert the gadget you should have the very same list like this :

[image]

if none of these steps are ok then I suggest you re-create a new script by copy/pasting the code, publish it from the script editor of the site and retry... this is a pretty staightforward procedure and I don't know what could go wrong if you follow every step of it...

good luck ;)

Comment: well... i hadn't seen that in the insert menu there are 2 possibilities to onsert gadgets... was allways looking at hte wrong one..... so that ones solved.... sorry for the inconvenience... Bruno

Comment: glad to hear... if you think this answered your question than consider to mark it as answered. thanks

Answer (score 0):

in the insert menu there are 2 possibilities to insert gadgets (and the logic of that escapes me, that why it took so long to find...) the first one are public gadgets and the second one is the one i searched the whole time, with the local gadgets...

so problem solved, 
sorry for the inconveninence....

Bruno